# Core Data fetch request returning no objects for relationship fault

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my application, I need to create an instance of an `NSManagedObject` subclass without inserting it in a context.  I do so like this:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel;
NSEntityDescription *parentEntity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Parent"];
Parent *parent = (Parent *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:parentEntity
                                            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
parent.name = @"Jonny";

NSEntityDescription *childEntity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Child"];
Child *child = (Child *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:childEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
child.name = @"Kim";

[parent child];
```

When the user decides to store the objects, I do so here:

```
[self.managedObjectContext insertObject:self.parent];
    for (Child *child in self.parent.children) {
        [self.managedObjectContext insertObject:child];
    }

    NSError *err = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"error: couldn't save managed object context.  %@", err);
    }
```

When I check the length of the `children` property here, it's always `> 0`.  So far so good.

However, in my next view controller, when I try to retrieve these properties:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)fetchObjects {
NSMutableArray *parents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to execute fetch request.");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
}
else {
    for (id parent in result) {
        Parent *parent = (Parent *)parent;
        [parents addObject:parent];
    }
}
return favorites;
```

}

The length of the `children` property of every parent is always `0`.  Can't seem to figure out why.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this without inserting it into a context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual pattern to create managed objects and save or discard them later is to insert them into a *temporary context*.

Make your main context the parent context of this temporary context and then either `save` or just throw it away.